# Multiple moving average calculation in MYSQL - Facing speed issues in my codes

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate the simple moving averages for 4 intervals. The below code is working fine in the phpMyAdmin and producing the results, but it is not getting the data when it is consumed in the html page through php.

While testing with only one moving Average suquery (20D_MA), instead of 4 sub-queries, it produces the output in ~ 16-20 Seconds.

The purpose of the output is to build historical price charts with moving averages, the speed is the biggest constraint now. Kinldy request your suggestions to fine-tune my code to speed it up.

```
SELECT s1.StockName, s1.Date As Date1, s1.Close, 

(Select Avg(s2.Close) from Price_History AS s2 

   Where (s2.StockName = '$StockName') AND s2.Date BETWEEN Date_Add(s1.Date,INTERVAL-20 Day) AND s1.Date) as '20D_MA', 

(Select Avg(s2.Close) from Price_History AS s2 

   Where (s2.StockName = '$StockName') AND s2.Date BETWEEN Date_Add(s1.Date,INTERVAL-50 Day) AND s1.Date) as '50D_MA', 

(Select Avg(s2.Close) from Price_History AS s2 

   Where (s2.StockName = '$StockName') AND s2.Date BETWEEN Date_Add(s1.Date,INTERVAL-150 Day) AND s1.Date) as '150D_MA', 

(Select Avg(s2.Close) from Price_History AS s2 

Where (s2.StockName = '$StockName') AND s2.Date BETWEEN Date_Add(s1.Date,INTERVAL-200 Day) AND s1.Date) as '200D_MA' 

FROM Price_History AS s1 where s1.StockName = '$StockName'
```

### Sample Table and Data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Price_History (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    StockName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Close FLOAT NOT NUll,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

INSERT INTO Price_History (StockName, Date, Close)  VALUES
('3M India','2016-06-15','12649'),
('3M India','2016-06-16','12392.2'),
('3M India','2016-06-17','12428.2'),
('3M India','2016-06-20','12369.5'),
('3M India','2016-05-06','13202.8'),
('3M India','2016-05-05','13131.2'),
('3M India','2016-05-04','13200.5'),
('3M India','2016-05-03','13365.3'),
('3M India','2016-05-02','13521.5'),
('3M India','2016-04-29','13323.8'),
('3M India','2016-05-10','13242'),
('3M India','2016-05-09','13226.6'),
('3M India','2016-05-11','13247.3'),
('3M India','2016-05-12','13212'),
('3M India','2016-05-13','13098.7'),
('3M India','2016-05-16','13126.8'),
('3M India','2016-05-17','13059.1'),
('3M India','2016-05-18','13009.7'),
('3M India','2016-05-19','12655.8'),
('3M India','2016-05-20','12716.3'),
('3M India','2016-05-23','12980'),
('3M India','2016-05-24','12960.7'),
('3M India','2016-05-25','13074.8'),
('3M India','2016-05-26','13164.2'),
('3M India','2016-05-27','12699'),
('3M India','2016-05-30','12500.5'),
('3M India','2016-05-31','12415.2'),
('3M India','2016-06-01','12385.2'),
('3M India','2016-06-02','12473.5'),
('3M India','2016-06-03','12456.9'),
('3M India','2016-06-06','12517.8'),
('3M India','2016-06-07','12521.3'),
('3M India','2016-06-08','12638.2'),
('3M India','2016-06-09','12378.7'),
('3M India','2016-06-10','12193.5'),
('3M India','2016-06-13','12144.7');
```

Thank you in advance.

Warm Regards

Suresh

Comment: @ Strawberry, Thanks  for the guidance.